# Speeding up code inside for loop

Tags: r, performance, optimization

I have a dataframe that contains more than 2 millions records. I am only sharing the few records due to data security reasons .I wish you guys can understand my reason.

```
data <- data[order(data$email_address_hash),]
skip_row <- c()
data$hash_time <- rep('NA',NROW(data)) #adding new column to our data
rownames(data) <- as.character(1:NROW(data))
dput(droplevels(data))
structure(list(email_address_hash = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26", "35c0ef2c2a804b44564fd4278a01ed25afd887f8"
), class = "factor"), open_time = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c(" 04:39:24", 
" 09:57:20", " 10:39:43", " 19:00:09"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("email_address_hash", 
"open_time"), row.names = c(41107L, 47808L, 3973L, 8307L), class = "data.frame")

str(data)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ email_address_hash: Factor w/ 36231 levels "00012aec4ca3fa6f2f96cf97fc2a3440eacad30e",..: 7632 2 2 7632
 $ open_time         : Factor w/ 34495 levels " 00:00:03"," 00:00:07",..: 15918 5096 16971 24707
.

skip_row <- c()


data$hash_time <- rep('NA',NROW(data)) #adding new column to our data

rownames(data) <- as.character(1:NROW(data))

for(i in 1:NROW(data)){
#Skipping the email_address_hash that was already used for grouping 
  if(i %in% skip_row) next   
  hash_row_no <- c()
#trimming data so that we don't need to look into whole dataframe 


trimmed_data <- data[i:NROW(data),] 
  # Whenever we search for email_address_hash the previous one was ignored or removed from the check 

  #extracting rownames so that we can used that as rownumber inside the skip_row
  hash_row_no <-  rownames(trimmed_data[trimmed_data$email_address_hash==trimmed_data$email_address_hash[1],])
```

#note :- we know the difference b/w rownames and rownumber

```
#converting rownames into numeric so that we can use them as rowno      
hash_row_no <- as.numeric(hash_row_no) 


  first_no <- hash_row_no[1]
  last_no <- hash_row_no[NROW(hash_row_no)]
  skip_row <- append(skip_row,hash_row_no)

  data$hash_time[first_no] <- paste(data$open_time[first_no:last_no], collapse = "")
}
```

## Please note that I also tried the below approaches for to speed up the process but that seems to be ineffective

```
hash_row_no <-  rownames(trimmed_data[trimmed_data$email_address_hash==trimmed_data$email_address_hash[1],])
```

## converted dataframe to data.table

```
setDT(data)
```

## performed either of the operation gives times similar time

```
system.time(rownames(trimmed_data[trimmed_data$email_address_hash==trimmed_data$email_address_hash[1],]))

system.time(rownames(trimmed_data)[trimmed_data[["email_address_hash"]] == trimmed_data$email_address_hash[1]])
```

Can you guys help me to speed up my code as my data contains more than 2 millions records and it is taking more than 30 minutes and even more ?

Comment: "I wish you guys can understand my reason." Then you should explain your actual goal. Better performance can usually be achieved with a better algorithm.

Comment: I said this in context of data security. . The goal was to extract all the open time of a single person and write that in front of that customer and in a single row instead of multiple rows and remove the other entries of that customer

Comment: That is still not an adequate description of what needs to be done. So far I have understood that you want to `paste` together all `open_time` values for each unique `email_address_hash`. Is that a correct problem description?

Comment: Yes you are abs correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, .(open_times = paste(open_time, collapse = "")), by = email_address_hash]
#                         email_address_hash         open_times
#1: 35c0ef2c2a804b44564fd4278a01ed25afd887f8  09:57:20 19:00:09
#2: 0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26  04:39:24 10:39:43
```

Or possibly this:

```
data[email_address_hash == "0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26", 
     paste(open_time, collapse = "")]
#[1] " 04:39:24 10:39:43"
```

Comment: there is one problem . When I open it using View(data) it is showing only first open time . i.e. 09:57:20 in case of row1 and second time for the same customer in second row. In our case view is showing it in 4 rows

Comment: Please try to communicate more clearly. I have absolutely no idea what you are opening with `View` since the code in my answer doesn't assign the result (which you could do obviously).